# Determine if user is still using JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, actionlistener

I have one **main Window** in my Java application (JFrame). Now I want to determine if the user is still using the window. To achieve this I will run a timer for like 15 minutes and after the timer runs out, for example my application closes. So far so good but how can I determine if the user clicked on something in the window?

I want to reset my timer every time an action is performed on the main window itself. Of course I could add `actionListeners` (Action performed) to every element in my window but this seems to be "too much". Is there any `actionListener` that you can attach to you main frame (window) that listens to **any** action?

Comment: Have a look at `ToolKit.addAWTListener`, essentially, you need to monitor just about any event you can think off (which is supported by it), check to see if the event originated from within the frame (you can use the event's `source`, if it's a `Component`, then you can use `SwingUtilities. windowForComponent` and check if the windows are the same).  If the event originated in the window, restart the timer

Comment: here is excelent "inactivity monitor" by @camickr, based on events from AWTEventListener

Comment: "here", you might be missing a link?

Comment: @Flatron, link for "application inactivity" added as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the simplest solution would be to replace the event-queue with an own implementation:

```
EventQueue queue = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue();
queue.push(new MyEventQueue);
```

The implementation of `MyEventQueue` would look like this:

```
class MyEventQueue extends EventQueue{
    @Override
    public void postEvent(AWTEvent e){
        if(filterMatch(e) && getTimer() != null && getTimer().isRunning())
            getTimer().restart();

         super.postEvent(e);         
    }

    private bool filterMatch(AWTEvent e){
        return (e instanceof ActionEvent);
    }
}
```

This examplecode only resets the timer, if the user presses a button or causes any other `ActionEvent`. Just change the `filterMatch` method to match your requirements.

As @mKorbel mentioned another approach to this problem would be `Toolkit.addAWTEventListener`:

```
Toolkit.addAWTEventListener(
    new AWTEventListener(){
        void eventDispatched(AWTEvent e){
            if(getTimer() != null && getTimer().isRunning())
                getTimer().restart();
        }
    } , AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK | AWTEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK);
```

This example will reset the timer if any Mouse- or KeyEvent is fired.

Comment: @mKorbel oh, yeah, i always forget about the `Toolkit`-methods. Thanks, I'll add it and correct the rest of the problems

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Application Inactivity](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/24/application-inactivity/).

It uses a Timer to control the inactivity time period. Then is listens for a MouseEvent and KeyEvent. Whenever an event occurs, the timer is reset.

All you need to do is write an `Action` to be invoked when the Timer actually fires.